# xsl:fo - Add "z-index" to a text on top of an image

Tags: xslt, pdf, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I have a problem.

I need to set some kind of z-index, like you can use on the web in HTML/CSS.
Because I have a text on an image, and therefore I want to be sure that it looks good when printing.

Is there some "z-index" code I can use on theese fo:block elements?

Thanks!
/Daniel

Answer (score 1):

XSL-FO defines z-index property:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xsl-20011015/slice7.html#z-index
You have to check your formatting agent whether does support this property.

Comment: Aha, was it so easy. I will try it out. Thanks!